# Brief overview of the x264 library

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, codec

Im to migrate the x264 library into actionscript. And analyzing it is not trivial at all. How does x264 work exactly? Ive assumed it uses multi threads in encoding, is it possible for it to be single threaded? How feasible it is to be migrated in an actionscript 3.0 web project?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better encode your video on Server by using some command line utility like Flash Media Encoder or FFmpeg.

It is not feasible in a short term perspective to write your own x264 encoder in ActionScript based around ByteArray class.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But Ive already tried encoding in the server side using also FFMPEG and it is working. The reason Im trying to encode it in the client side is to decrease the data size the client is sending to server due to bandwidth limitations.

Comment: Unfortunately, On2 Vp6 codec cannot be used for live publishing. Only default codec sorenson spark can be used for live publishing video. The reason behind this is that VP6 codec takes more time to compress than video length which makes it impossible to use it for live video publishing so the On2 VP6 compression codec is not included by ADOBE in flash player. Only On2 Vp6 decoder is there in flash player to play On2 VP6 files.  http://askmeflash.com/qdetail/1295/how-we-can-use-video-codec-on2-vp6-sorenson-spark-h-264

Comment: You may be interested in Adobe AIR 2.0 solution based on NativeProcess to encode the captured video from webcam using h.264 codec and Adobe Live Media Encoder, more on this matter: http://balazs.sebesteny.com/implement-h264-live-streaming-with-adobe-air-20/